# Send/receive file over LAN with C# to/from Python

Tags: c#, python, sockets, raspberry-pi, lan

I'm pretty new to Python development and need some help.

I have a [Raspberry Pi B+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Specifications), and I'm planning on using it as a controller for household things (such as turning on a pool pump at a set time). I am pretty familiar with C# and was wondering if there was a way I could write a C# user interface to run on a laptop and send data in the form of a XML file to the Raspberry Pi over a LAN to tell the Pi what to do. I have written some code in C# and some code in Python to try to send and receive a file, but so far my tests have been unsuccessful.

I have some rudimentary code written in Python on the Raspberry Pi for controlling some GPIO pins and was wondering if a connection like this is even feasible of if I should rewrite my Python code into C# also.

Here is my C# send file function

```
public void SendFile(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        string IpAddressString = piIP;
        IPEndPoint ipEnd_client = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IpAddressString), portnumber);
        Socket clientSock_client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);

        string filePath = "";

        fileName = fileName.Replace("\\", "/");
        Console.WriteLine(fileName);

        while (fileName.IndexOf("/") > -1)
        {
            filePath += fileName.Substring(0, fileName.IndexOf("/") + 1);
            fileName = fileName.Substring(fileName.IndexOf("/") + 1);
        }

        byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileName);
        if (fileNameByte.Length > 5000 * 1024)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File size is more than 5Mb, please try with small file.");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Buffering ...");
        string fullPath = filePath + fileName;

        byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath);
        byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileData.Length];
        byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameByte.Length);


        fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
        fileNameByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
        fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length);

        Console.WriteLine("Connection to server...");
        clientSock_client.Connect(ipEnd_client);

        Console.WriteLine("File sending...");
        clientSock_client.Send(clientData, 0, clientData.Length, 0);

        Console.WriteLine("Disconnecting...");
        clientSock_client.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("File [" + fullPath + "] transferred.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.Message == "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it")
            Console.WriteLine("File Sending fail. Because server not running.");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("File Sending fail. " + ex.Message);
        return;
    }
    connected = true;
    return;
}
```

Here is my Python receive file function

```
import socket
import sys
s = socket.socket()
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 8080))
s.listen(3)

while True:

    #Accept connections from the outside
    (clientsocket, address) = s.accept()
    print(address)
    i = 1
    f = open('file_' + str(i) + ".xml", 'wb')
    i = i + 1
    while True:
        l = clientsocket.recv(1024)
        while l:
            f.write(1)
            l.clientsocket.recv(1024)
    f.close()

    sc.close()

s.close()
```

Again, so far, I am unable to even set up a connection between the two devices. Should I start over on the Pi and try C# instead of Python? Or am I missing something? I've given both devices a static IP address and hardcoded the IP addresses on both machine for now.

EDIT:
Here is the Console and stacktrace I get from C#:

```
Buffering ...
Connection to server...
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
File Sending fail. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 10.51.21.199:8080
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
at App1.Stuffs.SendFile(String fileName) in
...Projects\App1\App1\Stuffs.cs:line 308
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1684) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Is that `f.write(l)`? And what exactly the stacktrace?

Comment: @pnv It is supposed to be, but right now I am unable to get the C# program to send anything. Here is the console output and stacktrace:
Buffering
Connection to server
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
File Sending fail. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 10.51.21.199:8080
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
  at App1.Stuffs.SendFile(String fileName) in ...App1\Stuffs.cs:line 308

Comment: Since you try to integrate C# and Python, it may be worthwhile to consider using ironPython: "IronPython is an open-source implementation of the Python programming language which is tightly integrated with the .NET Framework."

Comment: @boardrider I don't think that using of Iron would make any difference as OP don't do anything specific either for Python or for C#.

Comment: Shouldn't "sc.close()" be "clientsocket.close()"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes it should. I was using online code as a reference and guess I left their variable name instead of using my own. Using C# to call a python script is not off the table for me as long as I am able to send/receive files and I don't want it to be difficult to install on a customer PC in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
s.bind(('', 8080))
```

to force the Raspberry Pi to listen on all available interfaces, as the `socket.gethostname()` might not be the interface you are actually expecting.

**UPDATE:**

Try this on the Raspberry Pi side:

```
import socket
import sys
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('', 8080))
s.listen(3)

i = 0

while True:

    #Accept connections from the outside
    (clientsocket, address) = s.accept()
    print(address)
    i = i + 1
    with open('file_' + str(i) + ".xml", 'wb') as f:
        while True:
            l = clientsocket.recv(1024)
            if not l:
                break
            f.write(l)

    clientsocket.close()

s.close()
```

Comment: Did not work. Now it says:
File Sending fail. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.51.21.199:8080
So it didn't refuse the connection. Could I be missing a handshake of some sort on the python side?

Comment: Got it to send the file and connect! Now I think the Pi is receiving the file and decoding it in a different way than C# sent the file. Whenever I try opening the .xml, it says the document is empty and showsca weird character in the text editor. Should I be encoding the file in a different way on C#?

Comment: @TheSilas Unlikely that this is encoding issue as you are not processing text on both sides, but binaries. The issue might occur because you adding file name to the file content in your C# code `byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileData.Length];` Are you processing that somehow on the Python side? If not then get rid of it and you'll get bitwise copy of your file on the Pi.

Answer (score 0):

I have two ways of accessing my Raspberry Pi from a Windows PC. The first is after installing Putty connection manager on the PC, where entering the RPi IP address produces a Terminal window on the PC, from where I can execute RPi programs.

The RPi is connected to a Windows Workgroup, mapped as drive T:, in my case. My C programs can use this to create files on the RPi for writing or reading.